# Print string as hex literal python

Tags: python, string, escaping

I have a lot of pre-existing code that treats byte arrays as strings, i.e.

```
In [70]: x = '\x01\x41\x42\x43'
```

Which python always prints as:

```
In [71]: x
Out[71]: '\x01ABC'
```

This makes debugging a pain, since the strings I print don't look like the literals in my code.  How to I print strings as hex literals?

Comment: `print binascii.hexlify(data)`

Comment: @agf : I just learn something from. This was a good question and a good answer. I'd like to upvote your answer. Can you post it as an answer ?

Comment: Or assign like `x = r'\x01\x41\x42\x43'`.

Comment: @hivert Posted as an answer.

Comment: @J.Katzwinkel It's then not useable as binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a cross-version compatible solution, use [`binascii.hexlify`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii#binascii.hexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> x = '\x01\x41\x42\x43'
>>> print x
ABC
>>> repr(x)
"'\\x01ABC'"
>>> print binascii.hexlify(x)
01414243
```

As `.encode('hex')` is a misuse of `encode` and has been removed in Python 3:

```
Python 3.3.1
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> '\x01\x41\x42\x43'.encode('hex')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
LookupError: unknown encoding: hex
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your answer is close enough for my purposes.  I should be able to hack in printing with the backslashes so that what is printed is an actual literal....

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
>>> x = '\x01\x41\x42\x43'
>>> x.encode('hex')
'01414243'
```

or

```
>>> x = r'\x01\x41\x42\x43'
>>> x
'\\x01\\x41\\x42\\x43'
```

or

```
>>> x = '\x01\x41\x42\x43'
>>> print " ".join(hex(ord(n)) for n in x)
0x1 0x41 0x42 0x43
```

Answer (score 0):

To actually print out the string ~literal (i.e. the thing you can cut and paste back into your code to get the same object) requires something like:

```
>>> x = '\x1\41\42\43'
>>> print "'" + ''.join(["\\"+ hex(ord(c))[-2:] for c in x]) + "'"
'\x1\41\42\43'
```

Answer (score 0):

In **python3**, I generally write a small function to do this.

```py
def print_hex_string(data):
    result = ''

    for c in data:
        result += f'\\x{c:02x}'

    print("b'" + result + "'")
```

```py
x = b'\x01\x41\x42\x43'
print(x)
# b'\x01ABC'

print_hex_string(x)
# b'\x01\x41\x42\x43'
```

`binascii` is not needed since you can just do `x.hex()` for the same result.

```
print(x.hex())
# 01414243
```

**oneliner**:

```
x = b'\x01\x41\x42\x43'
print(''.join([f'\\x{c:02x}' for c in x]))
# \x01\x41\x42\x43
```